# Correct way to define a navigation property under .NET Core 3 Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I am very confused as I have found several different versions of how to correctly define navigation properties in Entity Framework under .NET Core 3. I found such versions as:

```
public List<MyObj> MyObjects {set; get;}
public List<MyObj> MyObjects {get;} = new List<MyObj>();
public virtual List<MyObj> MyObjects {set; get;}
public virtual List<MyObj> MyObjects {get;} = new List<MyObj>();
public ICollection<MyObj> MyObjects {set; get;}
public virtual ICollection<MyObj> MyObjects {set; get;}
```

And a few more. But which one is the most appropriate/up-to-date/correct version? According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships), the first one should be right, but I also found older articles with different writings.

Comment: I never used another type than the first. Is the simplest and the best declaration for a list (not array, not collection)

Comment: @AlleXyS I read, that you should mark them as virtual to allow lazy loading. I know, that this was a must in EF6 with the DB-first approach. But is that still the case in the new .NET Core world? Sorry for my stupid question, but this is my very first code-first project.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 distinct differences in your examples

1. `virtual` - You need to mark your proprties virtual to allow lazy-loading. This is a design decision and not dependant on the version (EF/EF Core).
2. `List<>` vs `ICollection` - Personal choice on what type of "collection" you would like to use `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`. You could even use `IEnumerable<T>`
3. Getter with Property Initializer - This enforces non-null collections. I prefer to not use this pattern as it means a null means that I have not loaded the collection when not using lazy-loading. Otherwise I wouldn't know whether I had retrieved the collection or it was just empty.

Each of these patterns are design choices and down to you to decide what makes sense to your app/coding style.

**TL:DR;** Use `virtual` if you're going to be using lazy-loading (try to avoid it myself) and use whatever type makes sense for your code. I prefer not to auto-initialise my collections, though.

**UPDATE** Setter with property initialiser was actually a getter - Updated answer

Comment: Regarding the setter: That's how it's actually tought in Microsoft's official tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli#create-the-model Would you say, that I shouldn't do that?

Comment: @AndréReichelt that example uses a getter, not a setter.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My hand-written code up there was wrong. I fixed it. So would you say, that writing something like `public List<MyObj> MyObjects {get;} = new List<MyObj>();` would make sense?

Comment: @AndréReichelt Definitely makes a difference, I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask, why you don't like lazy loading?

Comment: @AndréReichelt lazy-loading is very chatty - lots of small requests to the backend database. With eager/explict loading, I feel I'm more in control of the requests to the database and can make as many or few as I deem necessary.

Comment: But doesn't that mean, that EF will download the whole data structure with all sub tables on a simple select?

Comment: @AndréReichelt Nope, you have to explicitly `.Include()` the relationship to tell EF to populate the relationship. Not having collection property initialisers tells me when I've not included something I thought I had through the ubiquitous null-reference exception.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. After many years of auto lazy-loading in EF6, I just forgot how it actually works.

Comment: No problem. If my answer answered your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks